# Getting lots of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." errors on Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, pageload

we are getting a large amount of errors being reported from our website.

in Debug mode we are not seeing any and we cant seem to find a pattern.

about 1 in every 50-100 pageviews experience the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! thanks!

**Error**
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**StackTrace**
   at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Answer (score 0):

Without specifics it may be hard to diagnose. You could try to add more debug info into your release build in your project options for release configuration - this may then give you a line number.

Add some logging into there either through log4net or trace.write to try to get some more info out of this.

Is page_load accessing any httpcontext, cache, session, or application values?